# Definition of CNN Layers

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I hope you are all well.
I have to present an architecture of 1D CNN today and I am a bit confused. [image]I have a 1D Convolutional neural network Consisting of input data, 3 fully connected 1D convolution layers, flatten layer, batch normalization layer, 2 dense layers, and one output layer with a softmax activation function. I am interested in the terminology of the layers because I have to represent them in a good way.I am interested in the terminology of how the layers are called. For example the 3 fully connected convolution layers according to my opinion can be represented as just Convolution Layers, the flattening and the batch normalization layers can be represented as post-processing layers, the two dense layers can be represented as Tickening Layers and the output layer with the softmax activation function can be represented as Activation Layer. This is how I have them at the moment, If you think that I am wrong somewhere please make a comment.

Comment: The activation layer is definitely misleading since CNNs and Dense Layers have also activation functions...

Answer (score 0):

CNNs -> feature extraction

Flattering/Normalization -> downsampling

Denses -> fully connections

Softmax is actually an activation function, your CNNs have also activation functions. The softmax belongs to your dense layer part. When then I would call it as output layer

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for answering my question. I want to ask if you can provide me some information why the CNNs layers stands more for feature extraction rather than just convolution layers, flattering/normalization for downsampling and dense as fully connections layers. Thanks

Comment: convolution layers learn different filters/kernels that extract features from your images

Comment: I am doing the CNN on time-series tabular data, not on an image dataset.

Comment: it does not matter which type of data it is... it is about the construction of a convolution (image data was only an example)

Comment: Gaussian filter (as an example) can be applied on images as well as on time series... on both, it does smoothing... Imagine that convolution layers learn such different filters/kernels